# c# byte and bit casting - could this be done better?

Tags: c#, byte

I'm building arrays of bytes to be communicated over Bluetooth. These bytes are partly built from enumerated types, such as the following :

```
public enum Motor
{
   A = 0x00,
   B = 0x01,
   C = 0x02,
   AB = 0x03,
   AC = 0x04,
   BC = 0x05,
}
```

Later in my code I create a variable called MyMotor of type MyMotor.B. I then pass this variable to a method in which I build my byte array.

My issue is that the software I'm communicating with via Bluetooth expects the hex value of the enumerated value as a string, ie MyMotor.B = byte 0x01 = dec 1 = hex 31. However casting MyMotor directly to a char would result in it evaluating to it's enumerated value ie MyMotor = B = hex 42.

For various reasons I can't change my enurated list, so I've settled on what feels like a very hacked together two line section of code :

```
String motorchar = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(MyMotor)); // convert to temp var
command[5] = (byte)(motorchar[0]); // store hex value of var
```

It works as I'd like ie command[5] = hex31

I wonder if there's a better way. All the articles I've found talk about dealing with entire byte arrays rather than individual bytes and chars.

Comment: It seems your enum contains some base values and their combinations. That's what [[`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx)] is used for.

Comment: @svick: `A | C` does not give him `AC`.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I am assuming he creates the enum by himself and doesn't care about the actual values.

Comment: @svick: It doesn't look like he can do that to me...

Comment: @Mehrdad, ah, I didn't read the whole question. Okay, my comment is pointless here.

Answer (score 0):

```
chars[0] = (char)('0' + ((byte)myMotor & 0x0F));
chars[1] = (char)('0' + (((byte)myMotor & 0xF0) >> 4));
```

This needs a little more tweaking for hexadecimal, though.

Answer (score 0):

If your other app expects a string then provide one.
Make an array of strings to hold the values (which you know) and use the int value of the enum as an index into that array.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something your two line code is equivalent to just calling;

```
BitConverter.ToString(MyMotor);
```

No?

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried that in VS and see what your problem is. BitConverter expects a byte[] where as you have a single byte in your enum value. Move along, nothing to see here.

Comment: Bitconverter expects a byte array rather than a single byte

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your program's values and the values the API expects always differ by some fixed amount (for example, `AC = 0x04`, but the API wants "4", then you can write a simple conversion:

```
char c = (char)((int)Motor + '0');
```

That gets kind of ugly when there are more than 10 values, though. You can special case it for hexadecimal digits, but after that it's pretty bad.

You're better off creating a lookup table, the most general being a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Motor, string> MotorLookup = new Dictionary<Motor, string>() {
    { Motor.A, "0" },
    { Motor.B, "1" },
    // etc, etc.
};
```

That's going to be the most flexible and most maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
//If you want the ASCII representation.
//  e.g. myMotor == B, then the Byte Decimal value will be 49 or 0x31.
command[5] = (byte)((byte)myMotor).ToString()[0];
```

or

```
//If you want the numeric representation:
//  e.g. myMotor == B, then the Byte Decimal value will be 1 or 0x01.
command[5] = (byte)myMotor;
```

I see you using values like "0x01" and "0x05".  The "0x" prefix means it's a hexadecimal number, but you never go past 5, so it's exactly the same as using integer values "1" and "5".

I don't see how you're even getting Decimal 1 == Hex 31 or Hex 42 that you mention in your post.  The ASCII equivalent of Char '1' is Decimal 49 or Hex 31.